# convert single back slash to double back slash in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have one path e.g. "C:\home\my folder". I want to convert it into "C:\\home\\my folder". Please suggest me how can i use any function call to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you only need to escape back-slashes in *string literals*. For strings you read from a file or a user or other source you don't need it. Secondly, Windows handles forward slashes as path separator perfectly well, have worked since the DOS days.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually i am going to create directory tree using that path and i am using **SHCreateDirectoryEx()** and it needs the path with double back slash. I have tried that function with single front slash...but it didn't work!

Comment: @balla - I don't understand what you're trying to do, or you don't understand what the purpose of the double backslash is.  The only reason for a double backslash is for strings *in your program source code*.  If you are getting the directory name from user input, a file, or some other external source, you don't need to change anything.

Comment: @baila - `I have one path e.g. "C:\home\my folder`  So you're saying that another C++ function gave you that string, as-is?  Then that function is wrong.  That is not a path, that is a string that contains invalid or unknown escape characters.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I am taking one path from user (which may not exist) and create that particular directory tree(including the new sub-directories as well). I have the user input with single back slash. How can i make the directory (including sub directories)?

Comment: @balla I can say it again -- the string is ok.  Don't change anything.  It came from user input, the string is valid.  If you don't believe me, why not do a simple test?  `{ string name; cin >> name; ...}`  If the user entered backslashes, you will see that the string `name` contains backslashes with no further need to do anything.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie then how can i make complete directory structure? I have tried **CreateDirectory()** before, but it fails to create nested sub directories.

Comment: What was the failure code of the `CreateDirectory` function? It will not create a path with intermediate directories that don't exist. "ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND: One or more intermediate directories do not exist; this function will only create the final directory in the path."

Comment: I just saw an earlier comment that you have already tried `SHCreateDirectoryEx`. What was the failure code that gave you?

Comment: It's returing zero. I am doing **CreateDirectory( "D:\Home\My folder", NULL);**. Here only "D" drive is present. I want to create both 'Home' and 'My folder' directroy.

Comment: @JamesAdkison - that `SHCreateDirectoryEx()` function requires folder path with double back slashes. Then only it is creating all the nested sub-folders. But i have the user input with single back slash.

Comment: @balla - I guess you didn't read the comments that I and others have made.  That line of code you posted contains invalid or unsupported escape characters such as `\M` and `\H`.  Did the compiler warn you of it?  Now, that is what you have to change to double backslashes because of that reason.  If on the other hand, you did this: `{ cin >> name; CreateDirectory(name.c_str(), NULL);`, then you don't need to fool around with `name` to put double backslashes.  The name is perfectly ok.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - i didn't find any warning. That path is the user input which comes with that single slash. Now what you suggest me to do?

Comment: @balla - This is where I think you're confused.  That line of code you posted requires you to put double backslashes because *it is a string literal in your code*.  If the string comes from user input, there is no need to do anything with it.  So which is it -- is it that line of code you have just shown, or is the string coming from user input?  If it is user input, then your issue has to do with creating a directory tree -- it has nothing to do with backslashes.

Comment: @baila See here:  http://ideone.com/aHR3A1  Note that the string literal has only a length of 10 because those backslashes are not backslashes, but escape characters.  Compare when the string comes from input.  Note how the string is complete without doing anything with the data?

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie. You really are genius. Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt. Now I am doing `SHCreateDirectoryEx(NULL, path.c_str(), NULL);` and it works great. Previously I was experimenting by putting the path with single slash.

Thanks a lot again! :)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this could be by using the Boost string algorithm library.

```
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo.html
```

Using the following command :

```
std::string newPath = boost::replace_all_copy(testStr, "\", "\\");
```

This would result in the replaced and newly formed string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have found that before. But i don't want to use that library. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;


int main() 
{

    ifstream lire("data.txt",ios::in);
    string text ;
    getline(lire,text);  //text contains your  repertory 
    cout<<text<<endl;    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < text.size();i++) 
    {
        if(text[i] == '\\')
        {
            text.insert(i,"\\") ;
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout<<text<<endl;

return  0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any in build command or procedure except this manual coding?
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @baila you could create one. Built-in functions are not special.

Comment: @baila ,  I'm agree  , use your  own  function  .It's an advice.

Comment: Jus  turn  my answer to  green .

Answer (score 0):

The following program works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    std::string myPath;
    std::cout << "Enter path to create: ";
    std::cin >> myPath;
    std::cout << "Path from user: " << myPath << "\n";
    ::SHCreateDirectoryEx(nullptr, myPath.c_str(), nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Run

As you can see the path taken from *user input* only uses a single back slash **but the directory is successfully created**.

```
Enter path to create: C:\a_path
Path from user: C:\a_path
```

I think you chasing the wrong problem, assuming the reason you asked this question is because your call to the `SHCreateDirectoryEx` function failed.

### Notes:

- When some Win32 API functions fail (e.g., CraeateDirectory) you must call `GetLastError` to actually get the error code, but this isn't the case for `SHCreateDirectoryEx` (i.e., it returns the failure code directly).
- The `SHCreateDirectoryEx` function also works for me if I use forward slashes.